# How to create a 3D plane from a scatter of data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, average, data-analysis, plane

### Goal - Create a plane surface from a scatter of XYZ data in Matlab

**Description:**
Looking for a way to create a plane from a large data set.
The data set is measurement data from the scanning of a surface which is not perfectly flat, and it doesn't come in flat to any plane, and therefore makes statistical analysis difficult.

The goal is to find a plane which best represents most of the points, and then align it to the XY plane in order to extract information from it.

The image attached is a plot of the data. The color denotes the height.  Note: ignore the small blue dots, that is other data I need not worry about.

---

**How the data is structured:**

The data comes in as an N X 3 array

- X is first column
- Y is second column
- Z is third column

The plane is nearly flat, but I need the "average plane" to be exactly aligned with the XY plane to account for other data which may not be as flat as this example.

After I find the "average plane" I would do matrix transformations to align it to the axis by finding the angles the plane makes with the XY, XZ, and YZ axes

---

Things I'm not looking for that I've also found in my search: finding a plane from 3 points or finding the "rolling" surface plot from the data using surf or delauny.

[Example of plotted surface data - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT6mx.jpg)

Comment: Are you familiar with [`slice`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html)?

Comment: I just looked into it a bit.  It looks to create a slice from the data given whatever parameters you feed it.  Unfortunately, the hard part is finding what that plane should be.  Because I need to automate the process to perform on many data sets, I'll need an automated way to find what the 3D rotations are of the plane which cuts through the majority of the data.

Comment: Well I guess you'll have to work then. First figure out the optimal plane (->optimization problem), then use `slice` to infer your data along that plane (->interpolation problem).

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5Dfit+a+plane+to+points](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5Dfit+a+plane+to+points)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `fit`?

```
ft = fit([X, Y], Z,'poly11');
UnnormPlaneNorm = [ft.p10; ft.p01; -1];
planeNorm = UnnormPlaneNorm / norm(UnnormPlaneNorm);
angleXY = acos([0,0,1] * planeNorm);
angleXZ = acos([0,1,0] * planeNorm);
angleYZ = acos([1,0,0] * planeNorm);
```

Comment: Aren't those quantities inside the `acos` simply the 3 components of `planeNorm`?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to show the math behind it so the OP could use a general plane

Answer (score 0):

4 steps:

% 1. Compute the center of the data

% 2. Subtract off the center from the data

% 3. Fit a 2D plane to the centered data

% 4. Add the computed center back in

First, I am going to generate a set of random data that lies in a plane:

```
clear;close all;clc;

% Create a random set of data 
mag = 20;
N   = 1000;
A   = 2 * mag * ( rand( N, 3 ) - 0.5 );

% We want to make sure that the data lies in a plane, so let's reduce it
% with the svd
[ U, S, V ] = svd(A,'econ');
S(3,3)      = 0;
A           = U * S * V.';

% Now we are going to offset the plane from the origin by a random point 
p   = 100 * rand(1,3); 
A   = A + repmat( p, N, 1 );

% Make sure we have the dataset we want by viewing from different angles
figure 
subplot(1,3,1)
plot3(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),'.')
hold on
grid minor
view([1,1,1])
subplot(1,3,2)
plot3(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),'.')
hold on
grid minor
view([1,-1,1])
subplot(1,3,3)
plot3(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),'.')
hold on
grid minor
view([-1,1,1])
```

[image]
Now, at this point, the data in A lies perfectly in a plane. But we want noisy data to make sure out algorithm is working. So let's add noise back in:

```
% Now let's add some noise to our data 
B   = A + randn(size(A));
```

Now we start to fit a plane to the data...

```
% 1. Compute the center of the data 
c   = mean(B);

% 2. Subtract off the mean from the data 
D   = B - repmat( c, N, 1 );

% 3. Fit a 2D plane to the centered data 
[ U, S, V ] = svd( D, 'econ' );
S(3,3)      = 0;
D           = U * S * V.';

% 4. Offset by the computed center
D   = D + repmat( c, N, 1 );

% 5. Visualize by comparing with the noisy data
figure
subplot(1,3,1)
plot3(B(:,1),B(:,2),B(:,3),'.')
hold on
plot3(D(:,1),D(:,2),D(:,3),'.')
grid minor
view([1,1,1])
subplot(1,3,2)
plot3(B(:,1),B(:,2),B(:,3),'.')
hold on
plot3(D(:,1),D(:,2),D(:,3),'.')
grid minor
view([1,-1,1])
subplot(1,3,3)
plot3(B(:,1),B(:,2),B(:,3),'.')
hold on
plot3(D(:,1),D(:,2),D(:,3),'.')
grid minor
view([-1,1,1])
```

[image]